# Chartjs Bar chart shows undefined values

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, chart.js

I'm getting an array via json_encode() to draw a bar chart in chartjs using jquery. However the label and the data show as undefined. The console.log() displays the json array correctly.

Bar chart:
[image: example of incorrect chart]

Console log:
[image: console log showing json output]

```php
$arr = [
    [
        "Btype" => 1,
        "amount" => 3
    ],
    [
        "Btype" => 2,
        "amount" => 5
    ],
    [
        "Btype" => 3,
        "amount" => 7
    ],
];

print json_encode($arr)
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url:"http://localhost/scripts/draw.php",
        method: "GET",
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
            var b_type = [];
            var number = [];

            for(var i in data){
                b_type.push("BT " + data[i].BType);
                number.push(data[i].amount);
            }

            var chart = {
                labels: b_type,
                datasets: [
                    {
                        label: b_type,
                        backgroundColor: 'rgba(200,200,200,0.75)',
                        borderColor: 'rgba(200,200,200,0.75)',
                        hoverBackgroundColor: 'rgba(200,200,200,1)',
                        hoverBorderColor: 'rgba(200,200,200,1)',
                        data: number
                    }
                ]
            };

            var ctx = $("#myChart");

            var barGraph = new Chart(ctx, {
                type: 'bar',
                data: chart
            });

        },
        error: function(data){
            console.log(data);
        }
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a simple typo here:

```
b_type.push("BT " + data[i].BType);
```

`data[i].BType` should be `data[i].Btype` (note the lowercase `t` in `Btype`).

Here's a working example (AJAX code removed):

```js
let data = [{
  "Btype": 1,
  "amount": 3
}, {
  "Btype": 2,
  "amount": 5
}, {
  "Btype": 3,
  "amount": 7
}];

var b_type = [];
var number = [];

for (var i in data) {
  // b_type.push("BT " + data[i].BType); // <-- typo: JSON has a lowercase "t"
  b_type.push("BT " + data[i].Btype); // <-- fixed
  number.push(data[i].amount);
}

var chart = {
  labels: b_type,
  datasets: [{
    label: b_type,
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(200,200,200,0.75)',
    borderColor: 'rgba(200,200,200,0.75)',
    hoverBackgroundColor: 'rgba(200,200,200,1)',
    hoverBorderColor: 'rgba(200,200,200,1)',
    data: number
  }]
};

var ctx = $("#myChart");

var barGraph = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: chart
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.8.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I can't believe how i missed that. It worked perfectly. I still had to add  "data = JSON.parse(data);" first thing after the function. I don't quite get why that is but now it works.

Comment: @Julian You’re welcome. Try adding `dataType:”json”` to the `$.ajax` parameters.